# RecyclerView setting a image in the wrong place

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-adapter, recyclerview-layout

I have a recycle view, 2 differents adapter and I have a default Image. The problem is that when a user doesn't have an image, sometimes it loads an other user image instead of the default image. 
(I also check if user doesn't have imagelink, it reset the default image programatically... so it should work => no problem for the text etc, only the image!)

Here is the xml code for one adapter (pretty much the same for the other):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rella_rc_item_friend"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorCardView"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey_200"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:gravity="center">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/icon_avata"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/default_avata"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity=""
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txtTime"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>




            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity=""
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

```
class ListContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

public List<MessageInfo> ListContacts;
private Context context;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String currentuserid;
SimpleDateFormat DateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat TimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
SimpleDateFormat YearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat DayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, hh:mm a");

FusionProject Fobj = new FusionProject();

DatabaseReference VuRef;

CommunActivit obj = new CommunActivit();

public ListContactAdapter(Context context,List<MessageInfo> listGroup){


    this.context = context;
    this.ListContacts = listGroup;
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentuserid = mAuth.getUid();
    VuRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Seen");
}
public ListContactAdapter ()
{

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == 1) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rc_item_contact_me, parent, false);
        return new ItemForMe(view);
    } else if (viewType == 2) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rc_item_friend, parent, false);
        return new ItemForMyFriend(view);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position)

{
    String username = ListContacts.get(position).getFriendUsername();
    String last_message = ListContacts.get(position).getLastMessage();
    String time = ListContacts.get(position).getTime() ;
    String image = ListContacts.get(position).getFriendPicture();
    String FriendID = ListContacts.get(position).getFriendID();
    Date Today = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

    long yourmilliseconds = (Long.parseLong(time));

    Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
    String test = DateFormat.format(resultdate).toString(); /**DATE**/
    String test2 = TimeFormat.format(resultdate).toString(); /**TIME**/
    String test3 = YearFormat.format(resultdate);
    String test4 = DayFormat.format(resultdate);



    if (holder instanceof ItemForMe)
    {

        ((ItemForMe) holder).username_friend.setText(username);
        ((ItemForMe) holder).last_message.setText("Me : " +last_message);


        if (DateFormat.format(Today).equals(test))
        {
            ((ItemForMe) holder).time.setText(test2);
        }
        else
        {
            if (YearFormat.format(Today).equals(test3))
            {

                String cap = test4.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + test4.substring(1);
                ((ItemForMe) holder).time.setText(cap);
            }
            else {

                ((ItemForMe) holder).time.setText(test);
            }

        }
        if (!image.equals("")) {
            Picasso.get().load(image).into(((ItemForMe) holder).Profil_friend);
        }
        else
            {

            ((ItemForMe) holder).Profil_friend.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_avata);

        }

        VuRef.child(ListContacts.get(position).getIDMessage()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().equals("Vu"))
                    {
                        ((ItemForMe) holder).imageView_vu.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icons8_seen));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((ItemForMe) holder).imageView_vu.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icons8_not_vu));
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



    }
    else
    {


        ((ItemForMyFriend) holder).username_friend.setText(username);
        ((ItemForMyFriend) holder).last_message.setText(last_message);
        if (DateFormat.format(Today).equals(test))
        {
            ((ItemForMyFriend) holder).time.setText(test2);
        }
        else
        {
            if (YearFormat.format(Today).equals(test3))
            {


                String cap = test4.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + test4.substring(1);
                ((ItemForMyFriend) holder).time.setText(cap);
            }
            else {

                ((ItemForMyFriend) holder).time.setText(test);
            }

        }

        if (!image.equals("")) {
            Picasso.get().load(image).into(((ItemForMyFriend) holder).Profil_friend);
        }
        else
        {
            ((ItemForMyFriend) holder).Profil_friend.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_avata);
        }

    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent groupeIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ChatActivity.class);

            Fobj.writefile("FriendID",ListContacts.get(position).getFriendID(), context);
            Fobj.writefile("MessageID",ListContacts.get(position).getIDMessage(), context);
            Fobj.writefile("FriendName",ListContacts.get(position).getFriendUsername(), context);
            Fobj.writefile("FriendPicture",ListContacts.get(position).getFriendPicture(), context);

            obj.setsIDFRIEND(ListContacts.get(position).getFriendID());
            obj.setsIDMESSAGE(ListContacts.get(position).getIDMessage());
            obj.setsFRIENDName(ListContacts.get(position).getFriendUsername());
           context.startActivity(groupeIntent);


        }
    });
}




 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    String test = ListContacts.get(position).getSenderID();
    if (test.equals(currentuserid))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        {
            return 2;

    }
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ListContacts.size();
}
  }
```

Retrieve data :

```
  List_of_friends.add(0,new MessageInfo(ID, newgroup, profilepicture,MessageID, Date, Message, Time, SenderID));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So as you can see on this image, the first message wasn't loaded correctly. The user doesn't have an image but get the image user of one other user...

If anyone can help, would be nice !

I have debugged and it seems that it sometimes go more times in the holder than in the listsize.

[image]

Comment: I think issue is with Picasso loading images asynchronously ending up "leaking" image after viewHolder is reused.

Comment: It sometimes happens that image urls are invalid, so at that time we have to use error placeholders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with Glide like this.

Add this in app.gradle file

```
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0"
annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0"
```

Replace Picasso with glide like this

```
if (!image.trim().isEmpty())    
Glide.with(context).load(image).into(((ItemForMyFriend) holder).Profil_friend);
```

Comment: This threw me some errors like this : "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method into(Landroid/widget/ImageView;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/request/target/Target; in class Lcom/bumptech/glide/RequestBuilder; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder' appears in /data/app/com.example.thomas.fusionproject-ZK6PJfI0aW3tLLoZ4zxdnA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)" 

I'll look on the net later cause I must go and let you know, thank you

Comment: No, it runs and it crashes in the fragment. 
I have found a other solution  : I uploaded the link of the avatar image in the internet and called it when image is empty

Answer (score 1):

Try loading image like this in your recyclerview

```
if (!image.trim().isEmpty())    
   Picasso.with(context).load(image)
      .error(R.drawable.default_avata)
      .placeholder(R.drawable.default_avata)
      .into(((ItemForMyFriend) holder).Profil_friend);
```

Comment: @ImNeos, Let me know if it still not works for you !

Comment: I replaced my *if (!image.equals("")) {
                Picasso.get().load(image).into(((ItemForMe) holder).Profil_friend);
            }* with your code but still sometimes it loads the wrong image


I even tried to remove the *else
            {
                ((ItemForMyFriend) holder).Profil_friend.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_avata);
            }* 
but it doesn't change anything... it's weird because in my case I only have 5 cells and they takes all the screen so the view aren't even recycled

Comment: At both the places in your adapter ?

Comment: Yes at both places

Comment: May be it is possible that it is due to Picasso, You can try glide also

Comment: But it's weird because I use this code almost for  all of  my application and it does that only for this one... 
It is a fragment in tablayout, I don't know it if changes anything